# Selected value is not displayed in async mode

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I've got a react-select that I'm populating asyncly.  The items display just fine however, after an item is selected the list reverts to Loading..., the spinner starts spinning and nothing appears in the select box.

I can only guess the selected value is not being persisted?? not sure.  Complete=true in autocompleteLoad() has no affect.  Setting isLoading=false has no affect. Here's the code...

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';
import * as models from '../models'
import Select from 'react-select'
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css'

interface MovieActorState {
actor: models.Actor[]
loading: boolean
activeMovieId: number
activeActorId: number
acLoading: boolean,
acLabel?: string
}

const data = [{ value: 1, label: 'Mr Holland\'s Opus' },
{ value: 2, label: 'Braveheart' },
{ value: 3, label: 'Batman Forever' },
{ value: 1004, label: 'Star Wars' },
{ value: 1005, label: 'Goonies' },
{ value: 1006, label: 'ET' }];

const actors = [{ Id: 1, Name: 'Mel Gibson', Gender: 'Male', Age: 54, Picture: null },
{ Id: 2, Name: 'Val Kilmar', Gender: 'Male', Age: 49, Picture: null },
{ Id: 3, Name: 'Micheal Keaton', Gender: 'Male', Age: 60, Picture: null },
{ Id: 1002, Name: 'Diane Keaton', Gender: 'Female', Age: 49, Picture: null },
{ Id: 1003, Name: 'Tom Cruise', Gender: 'Male', Age: 55, Picture: null },
{ Id: 1006, Name: 'Richard Simmons', Gender: 'Male', Age: 59, Picture: null }];

const movieactors = [{ MovieId: 1, ActorId: 1 },
{ MovieId: 1, ActorId: 2 },
{ MovieId: 1, ActorId: 3 }];

export class Test extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, MovieActorState> {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.that = this;
    this.state = {
        actor: [],
        loading: true,
        activeMovieId: 0,
        activeActorId: 0,
        acLoading: false
    };
    console.log('movieactor.fetch()', this.state)
    this.setState({
        actor: actors,
        loading: false,
    });
}

that;

public render() {
    console.log('movieactor.render', this.state)
    let contents = this.state.loading
        ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
        : this.renderTable(this.state.actor, true);
    return <div>
        <h1>MovieActor</h1>
        <label>Movie</label>
        <Select.Async
            name="form-field-name"
            loadOptions={this.autocompleteLoad}
            valueKey="value"
            labelKey="label"
            onChange={this.autocompleteSelect.bind(this)}
            placeholder="Type to search"
            value={this.state.activeMovieId + ''}
            isLoading={false}
            onClose={this.autocompleteClose.bind(this)}
        /><br />
        {contents}
    </div>;
}

autocompleteSelect(e) {
    console.log('movieactor.autocompleteSelect()', e, this.state)
    this.setState({
        actor: actors.filter((actor) => {
            return (actor.Id > e.value);
        }),
        loading: false,
        activeMovieId: e.value,
        acLoading: false,
        acLabel: e.label
    });
}

autocompleteClose(e) {
    console.log('movieactor.autocompleteClose()', e, this.state)
    this.setState({ acLoading: false });
}

autocompleteLoad(input, callback) {
    console.log('autocompleteLoad(' + input + ')')
    if (input == null || input.length == 0) {
        console.log('null')
        callback(null, { complete: true })
        return;
    }
    callback(null, {
        options: data, complete: true
    })
};

private renderTable(actor: models.Actor[], allowSort: boolean = false) {
    let headings = this.renderTableHeadings(allowSort)
    return <table className='table'>
        <thead>
            {headings}
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {actor.map(item =>
                <tr key={item.Id}>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>{item.Id}</td>
                    <td>{item.Name}</td>
                    <td>{item.Gender}</td>
                    <td>{item.Age}</td>
                    <td>{item.Picture}</td>
                </tr>
            )}
        </tbody>
    </table>;
}

private renderTableHeadings(allowSort: boolean) {
    return <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Picture</th>
    </tr>
}
}
```

Update: In my on-going effort to get this to work, it seems the hidden input with the value is missing.  According to the react-select docs:

[image: react-select Usage]

..but when I inspect the dom (after selecting item) it's not there...
[image]

I'm going to give this another day, before I replace the component with something else.

Comment: Can you create a plnkr for this?

Comment: Tried, but plnkr is not very friendly.  Is there an easier upload site?

Comment: updated the code above. now shows the whole component.

Answer (score 0):

Code is working 100% fine,

Please check the **[WORKING DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/482z4v8q7x)** , there might be some other code that would be affecting issue.

Comment: I think i see the confusion....the code that I supplied 'works' but not the way I would like.  What would be ideal is for the selected value to remain displayed in the Select control after it is selected, not disappear.  This seems to be a deficiency in the component.  Users are busy people if they are distracted the will easily forget which value they selected and potentially make of mess of things updating the wrong record.  My real-world application isn't as trivial as the movie database in this example.

Comment: @alexb, you can do is show selected value, and you are also saving selected value inside `this.state.acLabel` , please check Working demo again , I have changed the code .

Comment: Thanks for the workaround.  I was hoping for a fix since I have the same problem on another component and having the value disappear after the user selects it is pretty lame.